When saving my RDLC report as a PDF from the Report Viewer, it is duplicating the pages
I have created the RDLC report with one page, and it shows like that in the Report Viewer too:

But whenever I select to save as a PDF, it duplicates that page:

I have tried changing the size, removing all variables, but nothing seems to work.
Here is the code used to generate the report:
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MediniApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@";");
        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Owner",con);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("Owner",dt);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Report1.rdlc";
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}


The report viewer probably is showing both pages if you scroll down. The error is in the RDLC file which is HTML.  You can open the RDLC file with any text editor to check why two pages are being created.

@jdweng I thought so too, but in the report viewer you can see in the top left corner it says page 1/1. and also if i save it as doc, it shows only one page. The problem is only when i save it as PDF

The code you posted only shows the loading of the report viewer.  Where is the generation of the pdf?  Is the pdf being generated from the windows form or the rdlc webpage?  The report viewer is a browser.  It is not the form with "button1".

i dont use any code for PDF generation. in the report viewer, i press the save button and "save as PDF"

There must be code in the RDLC.  See if this helps : https://www.adelomar.com/posts/2019/07/export_ssrs_report_into_pdf_format_from_asp.net_application/


But whenever I select to save as a PDF, it duplicates that page

I have run into same problem and it was a mistake of my printing setting in my memory.
What is your printing settings when you print as PDF? Maybe some double pages settings here.

I am directly saving as PDF with the "save as" button, and not using print as PDF

Did you try print button? Would it print double pages too? And you can check "Page Setup" to find if there is anything weird.
